# What connector does the Raspberry Pi camera have?

Tags: raspberry-pi, identification, connector

I need an extension cable for the Raspberry Pi camera sensor (the PCB is too big.)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please crop your photo and measure the pitch of the connector.

Comment: It's a board-to-board connector. There are many varieties available, e.g. [toby.co.uk](https://www.toby.co.uk/board-to-board-pcb-connectors/) shows lots of pictures of them. The V2 camera uses a Hirose DF37NC-30DS-0.4V connector (not the same as the V1.3 camera) from its [schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/schematics/rpi_SCH_Camera2_2p1.pdf), if that leads you to anything.

Comment: Careful googling will give you links to buy the extension cable. It would be easier to buy a ready-made cable than make one up yourself.

Comment: mezzanine connector https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mezzanine+connector&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Were you able to find an extension cable? I'm also looking for one

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an extension cable but if you search for IMX219 on Aliexpress, there are a number of sellers offering a replacement camera module that includes an 8cm permanently-attached cable.  You'd think they'd be expensive as they include the camera as well but some of them are under $10.

They don't include the Pi camera PCB so you need a V2 camera already in order to be able to use it.  I haven't yet found a supplier of the bare PCBs unfortunately.

[image: Photo of camera sensor with long cable]